# Could not create or update Cloud Run service workwithfile, Container Healthcheck failed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy firebase cloud function ,but it bring me this error :

> Could not create or update Cloud Run service workwithfile, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'workwithfile-00004-jej' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

the code am trying to deploy is like :

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */

/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
 * const {onDocumentWritten} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */


// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

// exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
//   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
// const {logger} = require("firebase-functions");
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {createClient} = require("@supabase/supabase-js");
initializeApp();
const subaBaseURL = "the url removed for secuirty ";
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
const subaBaseKey = "the key removed for secuirty";
const supabase = createClient(subaBaseURL, subaBaseKey);

const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2");
setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10});

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
exports.workwithfile = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const name = req.query.text;
  const lastSlashIndex = name.lastIndexOf("/");
  const result =
    lastSlashIndex !== -1 ? name.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1) : name;
  if (result == "countries.json") {
    const publicUrl = supabase.storage
        .from("uploads")
        .getPublicUrl(`geojsons/countries/${result}`);
    const finalURL = publicUrl.data.publicUrl;
    const response = await fetch(finalURL);
    if (response.ok) {
      await deleteOldCountries().then(async (e) => {
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const toSendData = [];
        for (const item of jsonData.features) {
          const objectToAdd = {
            name_en: item.properties.name_en,
            name_ar: item.properties.name_ar,
            file_id: item.properties.file_id,
            title_ar: item.properties.title_ar,
            title_en: item.properties.title_en,
            object_id: item.properties.OBJECTID,
            file_url: finalURL,
          };
          toSendData.push(objectToAdd);
        }
        await updateCountriesData(toSendData);
      });
    } else {
      console.error(
          `Failed to fetch JSON from ${finalURL}. Status: ${response.status}`,
      );
    }
  }
  if (result == "governorates.json") {
    const publicUrl = supabase.storage
        .from("uploads")
        .getPublicUrl(`geojsons/governorates/${result}`);
    const finalURL = publicUrl.data.publicUrl;
    const response = await fetch(finalURL);
    if (response.ok) {
      await deleteOldGovernorates().then(async (e) => {
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const toSendData = [];
        for (const item of jsonData.features) {
          const objectToAdd = {
            name_en: item.properties.name_en,
            name_ar: item.properties.name_ar,
            file_id: item.properties.file_id,
            title_ar: item.properties.title_ar,
            title_en: item.properties.title_en,
            parent_id: item.properties.parent_id,
            object_id: item.properties.OBJECTID,
            file_url: finalURL,
          };
          toSendData.push(objectToAdd);
        }
        await updateGovernoratesData(toSendData);
      });
    } else {
      console.error(
          `Failed to fetch JSON from ${finalURL}. Status: ${response.status}`,
      );
    }
  }
  if (result.includes("level1")) {
    const publicUrl = supabase.storage
        .from("uploads")
        .getPublicUrl(`geojsons/level1/${result}`);
    const finalURL = publicUrl.data.publicUrl;
    const response = await fetch(finalURL);
    if (response.ok) {
      await deleteOldLevel1().then(async (e) => {
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const toSendData = [];
        for (const item of jsonData.features) {
          const objectToAdd = {
            name_en: item.properties.name_en,
            name_ar: item.properties.name_ar,
            file_id: item.properties.file_id,
            title_ar: item.properties.title_ar,
            title_en: item.properties.title_en,
            parent_id: item.properties.parent_id,
            object_id: item.properties.OBJECTID,
            file_url: finalURL,
          };
          toSendData.push(objectToAdd);
        }
        await updateLevel1Data(toSendData);
      });
    } else {
      console.error(
          `Failed to fetch JSON from ${finalURL}. Status: ${response.status}`,
      );
    }
  }
  res.json({result: `file done proccing: ${result}.`});
});

async function updateCountriesData(toSendData) {
  const {data, error} = await supabase
      .from("countries")
      .insert(toSendData)
      .select();
}

async function updateGovernoratesData(toSendData) {
  const {data, error} = await supabase
      .from("govs")
      .insert(toSendData)
      .select();
}

async function updateLevel1Data(toSendData) {
  const {data, error} = await supabase
      .from("gov_sub_level_1")
      .insert(toSendData)
      .select();
}

async function deleteOldCountries() {
  const {data: toDeleteData} = await supabase
      .from("countries")
      .select("*");
  for (const singleCountry of toDeleteData) {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("countries")
        .delete()
        .eq("id", singleCountry.id);
  }
}

async function deleteOldGovernorates() {
  const {data: toDeleteData} = await supabase
      .from("govs")
      .select("*");
  for (const singleGov of toDeleteData) {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("govs")
        .delete()
        .eq("id", singleGov.id);
  }
}
async function deleteOldLevel1() {
  const {data: toDeleteData} = await supabase
      .from("gov_sub_level_1")
      .select("*");
  for (const singleItem of toDeleteData) {
    const {data, error} = await supabase
        .from("gov_sub_level_1")
        .delete()
        .eq("id", singleItem.id);
  }
}
```

it works perfectly when i run `firebase emulators:start` but i get this error when i run `firebase deploy --only functions`